# Dynamically derive dataframe names for assignment

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have array of columns. For each of the column in the array, I need to perform same operation and create in a separate dataframe. So that later these dataframes can be merged/joined into one.

with below, getting error : cannot assign to expression here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?

I get that the issue is due to we dynamically trying to derive the dataframe name using c +'_df_name' for which we are assigning the data.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

data = [("John", 25), ("Alice", 30), ("Bob", 35)]
columns = ["name", "age"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

attributes = ["name","skill"]

for c in attributes:
    c +'_df_name' = df.select(lit('xyz')) # simplified
```

So changed the above code as below:

```
for c in attributes:
    df_name = c +'_df_name'
    print(df_name) # prints name_df_name, skill_df_name
    df_name = df.select(lit('xyz')) # simplified
```

Now if change try to print the new dataframe value using below, getting error.name 'name_df_name' is not defined.

```
name_df_name.show()
skill_df_name.show()
```

How do we dynamically generate unique dataframe names for each assignment during the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a dataframe to a string literal instead of a container.

```py
data_frames = {f"{c}_df_name": df.select(lit('xyz')) for c in attributes}
```

By using a dictionary, the list of dataframe names is accessible using the `keys` method.

```py
data_frames.keys()
```

The individual dataframes can be accessed using the appropriate key string.
e.g.

```py
data_frames["abc_df_name"]
```

**Further Explanation:**

```py
attributes = ["name","skill"]

for c in attributes:
    c +'_df_name' = df.select(lit('xyz')) # simplified
```

The for loop creates two **string literals**: "name_df_name", "skill_df_name". It's not possible to assign a value to a string literal, the assignment within the loop is a syntax error.

You cannot do this:

```py
"name_df_name" = 1
```

But you can do this:

```py
name_df_name = 1
```

If you wish to use your string literals then you could add them to the `locals()` dictionary, but this would be a dirty hack and is not recommended.

```py
attributes = ["name","skill"]

for c in attributes:
    _ = c +'_df_name'
    if _ not in locals():
        locals()[_] = df.select(lit('xyz')) # simplified
```

Comment: just curious, why it cannot be done without dictionary, as I have done earlier? In general when we have single datafarme, we dont use dictionary, instead we just assign using any variable as above. Could you please elaborate for me to understand?

Comment: Thanks Dan for the clear explanation in the update.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use dynamic variables.

Use a dictionary instead

```
myDataframes = {}
attributes = ["name","skill"]

for c in attributes:
   myDataframes[c + '_df_name'] = df.select(lit('xyz')) # simplified
```

this will generate the following dict:

```
{
  "name_df_name": SomeDataframe,
  "skill_df_name": SomeDataframe  
}
```

which you can access directly if you know the name of the keys:

```
myDataframes["name_df_name"]
```

or you can iterate through the different pairs of keys/values present in the dictionary:

```
for key, value in myDataframes.items():
```

Comment: just curious, why it cannot be done without dictionary, as I have done earlier?

Comment: because having dynamic variable names is a bad practice (it requires evaluating the expressions). If you need to have elements assigned to a name, a dictionary is the way to go. If you just need the elements themselves without a name to refer to them, then you have other options, like a list, a set... depending if you need the elements to have an order, to be unique... There's a data structure for each need.

Comment: In general when we have single datafarme, we dont use  any dictionary, instead we just assign using any variable as I have done. So could you please elaborate  as why we need to dictionary for me to understand?

Comment: if you just need a single variable to store a dataframe, why naming this variable with a dynamic name?  Imagine I have some function that does this. How do you know the name of the variable where I saved the dataframe? it's just easier if I save it to a static variable name, like your dataframe can be found in  `myDataframes` instead of being in `Dataframes124653`  Trust me, use a dictionary if you need to access the dataframes by name, otherwise if the name doesn't matter a list could also be an option.